# Facebook Batch Post Requests using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, post

I'm trying to make a batch request using PHP that make a post in the user wall without any luck.
I have succeed to make bath request of a type "GET" but not of a type "POST".

My code:

```
    $batched_request = '[{"method":"POST","relative_url":"me/feed","body": "message=hi"},' .
    '{"method":"GET","relative_url":"me/feed?limit=1"}]';

    $post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . "?batch=" 
    . $batched_request
    . "&access_token=" . $access_token . "&method=post";
    echo $post_url;

    $post = file_get_contents($post_url);
    echo '<p>Response: <pre>' . $post . '</pre></p>';
    $decoded_response = json_decode($post, true);
    print_r($decoded_response);
```

If I change $batched_request to be only:

```
$batched_request = '[{"method":"GET","relative_url":"me/feed?limit=1"}]';
```

The batch request will suceeded and will show me the first post of the user wall.. but what is my problem with my POST request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrapped the `$batched_request` within `urlencode()` and it worked like a charm:

```
$batched_request = '[{"method":"POST","relative_url":"me/feed","body": "message=hi"},' .
'{"method":"GET","relative_url":"me/feed?limit=1"}]';

$post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . "?batch=" 
. urlencode($batched_request)
. "&access_token=" . $access_token . "&method=post";
echo $post_url;

$post = file_get_contents($post_url);
echo '<p>Response: <pre>' . $post . '</pre></p>';
$decoded_response = json_decode($post, true);
print_r($decoded_response);
```

Also make sure you have granted the `publish_stream` permission.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

[This class](http://blog.pclabs.com.tr/gokhanozturk/2011/11/17/facebook-batch-requests-php-class/) will simplify making batch requests to Facebook.

Comment: Would you mind posting the code, or instructions here? If the website went down, or shut down, we would have no information here.

Comment: And in both sites the page was not found. Information lost